# HIVE - Insert sql fail because missing table

Tags: sql, hive

I need some help. I want to insert record into HIVE database the table name is test but the problem is I an encounter error as below although i have test table

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:12 missing TABLE at 'test' near 'test' in select clause
line 1:24 cannot recognize input near '(' 'aaaa' ',' in select clause
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 40000
```

Any idea why?

Comment: you can not expect anyone to help without the query that causes the error.

Comment: I have update sql query as above. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its okay. I have manage to find an answer where my insert statement for HIVE should be as below

```
INSERT INTO TABLE <TABLE_NAME>(<COLUMN>) VALUES(<VALUES>);
```